# How might I store in a variable the string read by fgets() without leaking memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, fgets

I want the following code to accomplish to store the content of the file it reads in a variable
`content` without leaking memory:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    const size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1); 
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2 + 1); 
    return result;
}

int main() {

char path[] = "/home/jim/trackers_best.txt";
FILE *archivo = fopen(path,"r");
char line[200];
char * content = "";


if (archivo == NULL)
        exit(1);
else {

fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_END);
  int sz = ftell(archivo);
  fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_SET);
  if (sz < pow(10, 7) ) {
        printf("\nThe content of %s is:\n", path);
        while (feof(archivo) == 0) {
        fgets(line, 200, archivo); //reads one line at a time - comment out the while loop to find out
        content = concat(content, line);
       //free(content);//No leaks but no content either       
            }
          }
  else {
      puts("File take up more than 10 MBs, I refuse to read it.");
      fclose(archivo);
      exit(0);
        }
      }
fclose(archivo);
puts(content); 
free(content);
return 0;   
}
```

much the same as this code that uses `fread()` does it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 

int main() {
 
int count;  
char path[] = "/home/jim/trackers_best.txt";
FILE *archivo = fopen(path,"rb");
    
 if (archivo == NULL) {
     puts("Does not exist.");
     exit(1); 
       }
 else {
  
  fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_END);
  int sz = ftell(archivo);
  char contenido[sz];
  fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_SET);
  if (sz < pow(10, 7) ) {
    count = fread(&contenido, 10 * sizeof(char), sz, archivo);//reads 10 characters at a time.
    }
  else {
      puts("File take up more than 10 MBs, I refuse to read it.");
        }
  fclose(archivo);
  // Printing data to check validity
  printf("Data read from file: %s \n", contenido);
  printf("Elements read: %i, read %li byte at a time.\n", count, 10 * sizeof(char));
  
 }
return 0;   
}
```

The first code snippet leaks memory, as evidenced by valgrind:

```
...
total heap usage: 44 allocs, 4 frees, 23,614 bytes allocated
...
==404853== LEAK SUMMARY:
==404853==    definitely lost: 17,198 bytes in 40 blocks
...
```

When I attempt to prevent such leak by executing `free()` within the while loop I get no value stored in `content`. How might I store the string read by `fgets` without leaking memory?

Comment: Read this: [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `concat` the *second* time, the value from the *first* call is overwritten by the `malloc` call. That is the memory leak.

I presume that you want `content` to be one long string that contains the data from *all* lines.

You want to use `realloc` (vs. `malloc`) in `concat` and just append `s2` to the enlarged `s1`.

With this modified scheme, instead of `char *content = "";`, you want: `char *content = NULL;`

Also, don't use `feof`

And, `ftell` returns `long` and *not* `int`. And, it's better to *not* use `pow` to compare against the limit.

Here is the refactored code (I've compiled it but *not* tested it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char *
concat(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len1;
    size_t len2;

    if (s1 != NULL)
        len1 = strlen(s1);
    else
        len1 = 0;

    len2 = strlen(s2);

    s1 = realloc(s1,len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (s1 == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    memcpy(s1 + len1, s2, len2 + 1);

    return s1;
}

int
main(void)
{

    char path[] = "/home/jim/trackers_best.txt";
    FILE *archivo = fopen(path, "r");
    char line[200];
#if 0
    char *content = "";
#else
    char *content = NULL;
#endif

    if (archivo == NULL)
        exit(1);

    fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz = ftell(archivo);
    fseek(archivo, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    if (sz < (10 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        printf("\nThe content of %s is:\n", path);

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), archivo) != NULL)
            content = concat(content, line);
    }
    else {
        puts("File take up more than 10 MBs, I refuse to read it.");
        fclose(archivo);
        exit(0);
    }

    fclose(archivo);

    if (content != NULL)
        puts(content);

    free(content);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested, it works. Why is it better to avoid `pow` when comparing against the limit? I did choose it for the sake of readability, i.e. the alternative notation of  `10000000` has so many zeroes that I decided to use `pow(10, 7)` instead.

Comment: `pow` is _not_ precise and it's slow and has to compute the value dynamically. Better to use fixed point math, particularly when dealing with memory sizes/offsets or file sizes/offsets. And, use a _constant_. Also, 1000 is _not_ a kilobyte [as _programmers_ define it]. It is 1024. So, 10 megabytes is: 10,485,760. This is `10 * 1024 * 1024` which will be constant folded by the compiler into a single constant. When dealing with this a lot, one could put the following in a header file (e.g.): `#define KB 1024 #define MB (1024 * 1024) #define GB (1024 * 1024 * 1024)` Then, just do: `10 * MB`

Answer (score 1):

You knew what you needed to do but didnt do it right

```
    content = concat(content, line);
   //free(content);//No leaks but no content either
```

you need to keep the old content pointer so you can delete it after you create a new one

```
    char *oldc = content;
    content = concat(content, line);
    free(oldc);
```

Comment: This is a problem on the first iteration because `char * content = "";` means `content` won't point to a block allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja `char * content = "";` is not correct? After applying the solution of @pm100  I get `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)` but when I do not initialize the pointer I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, i forgot the first time case. realloc is the better answer, but you shoul dbe able to see whats wrong with my answer